# How to ignore a token and reset lexer lookahead index

Tags: antlr4

A couple of weeks ago I started to work with ANTLR4. I would like to know if there is a way to ignore a matched token by the lexer and reset the index position of the CharStream to the start position of the ignored token so that it can be matched again by other rule (for example other rule within a different mode).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe: <ruleName> : <rule> { _input.seek(_tokenStartCharIndex); skip(); };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds quite a bit like the `less` lexer command which was proposed but never fully defined:
[#212: A new lexer command: Less](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/212)

For now, I would override the `nextToken` command in your lexer.

```
@Override
public Token nextToken() {
    while (true) {
        int mark = input.mark();
        try {
            int startIndex = input.index();
            Token token = super.nextToken();
            if (token != null && token.getType() == MY_SPECIAL_TYPE) {
                pushMode(MY_SPECIAL_MODE);
                input.seek(startIndex);
                continue;
            }

            return token;
        }
        finally {
            input.release(mark);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. I think it is an interesting idea create a lexer command as is proposed in the link. Many thanks.